# Problems when reloading rows to update cell height in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` where I set the image in a `UIImageView` from an URL using `AFNetworking`. When the image is loaded I want to resize the image view and the cell in order to fit the image.

In my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I have the following code:

```
FeedItem *feedItem = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
FeedItemCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FeedItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:feedItem.thumbnailUrl];
[request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
    // first I set the height of the image view
    cell.thumbnailImageHeightConstraint.constant = image.size.height;
    // then I save the height in a dictionary to return it in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
    [thumbnailHeights setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:thumbnailHeight] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];

    // now I reload the cell in order to have the new height applied
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failed loading: %@", error);
}];
```

In my `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` I have this:

```
NSNumber *thumbnailHeightNumber = [thumbnailHeights objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
if (thumbnailHeightNumber != nil) { // image size has been calculated
    return thumbnailHeightNumber.floatValue;
}
return 0;
```

This sort of works. The height is set correctly on both the image view and the cell. However, there is some unpredictable behaviour:

1. When I scroll, some cells flash sometimes, as If being reloaded, which is annoying.
2. Sometimes wrong cells are shown in rows. Actually, the content of the cell returned by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is correct, but it displays content from one of the previous cells.
3. Sometimes a cell is completely blank. Again, inspecting its content it seems correct.

I have noticed something that might be related to the issue. My `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is always called twice, which I believe is actually causing my problems. If I remove the line `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];` it is only called once (for each row) and the problems stop, but of course then the height of the cell is not updated.

Also, I do not believe that the issue is related to the actual change in the cell height. If I set a fixed height for the image and the cell height, I still get the same side-effects when calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

So I am hoping that there is either a fix for this issue, or some other way of accomplishing my goal of dynamic cell height.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `setImageWithURLRequest:request:placeholderImage:success:failure:` is asynchronous, so `cell.thumbnailImageView` is going to be unpopulated or (if the cell is being re-used) have previous image data in it until `setImageWithURLRequest` succeeds, probably some time after `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` has already returned the cell. If `setImageWithURLRequest` fails, then your cell is left with an unchanged/unconfigured thumbnail image view.

You can provide an image in the `placeholder:` argument which will be displayed until the `success` block is called, then at least you also have a fallback for the failure case.

The table is likely to flash as the various cells' success blocks get called asynchronously some time later, each of them forcing a reload of different rows.

Unless you know the thumbnail images are all a fixed size in advance (and could then easily use a standard placeholder image), I'd suggest pre-loading the relevant thumbnail images before your table view's `numberOfRowsInSection:` changes its return value and thus triggers the calls to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That way you'll be able to return fully configured images in the cells.

Comment: I understand your point about asynchronous execution, but this is the way I found people do in on the internet, including the examples provided by `AFNetworking`. As I write, if I leave out the call to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` the issues don't happen, and the images are loaded just fine (in the correct rows).
Unfortunately, I don't know the size of the images, hence the entire exercise. I'm not sure that preloading images as you suggest is a good idea as I don't want to load all of them. `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is only called as cells are about to become visible.

Comment: Yes, good point about not wanting to preload all images unnecessarily. Could it be possible that the call to reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: isn't being called on the main thread?

Comment: Well, I guess it is possible, since it is being called from inside the completion block.